# What is the equivalent for java interfaces or objective c protocols in swift?

Tags: ios, macos, interface, protocols, swift

I've been looking in to the new Swift language trying to find what's the equivalent for an interface(in java) or a protocol(in objective-c) in Swift, after surfing on the internet and searching in the book provided by Apple, I still can't seem to find it.

Does any one know what's the name of this component in swift and what's its syntax?

Comment: There are protocols in Swift. [Docs link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_345)

Comment: "Protocols" - Page 464 of the Swift book

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Protocols in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) are very similar to Objc, except you may use them not only on classes, but also on structs and enums.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
     var fullName: String { get } // You can require iVars
     class func someTypeMethod() // ...or class methods
}
```

Conforming to a protocol is a bit different:

```
class myClass: NSObject, SomeProtocol // Specify protocol(s) after the class type
```

You can also extend a protocol with a default (overridable) function implementation:

```
extension SomeProtocol {
      // Provide a default implementation:
      class func someTypeMethod() {
           print("This implementation will be added to objects that adhere to SomeProtocol, at compile time")
           print("...unless the object overrides this default implementation.")
      }
}
```

*Note: default implementations must be added via extension, and not in the protocol definition itself - a protocol is not a concrete object, so it can't actually have method bodies attached. Think of a default implementation as a C-style template; essentially the compiler copies the declaration and pastes it into each object which adheres to the protocol.*

Comment: I got error. please help 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'SomeProtocol' where ViewController is my class where i have implemented the "SomeProtoco"

Comment: You have to implement the protocol methods as well in your MyClass.That why you are getting above error. In the same way in Java. When you implement a Interface in your class. You also implement the Abstract Methods.

Answer (score 10):

swift has protocols as well, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) is the relevant documentation: