# Protocols, willSet and didSet

Tags: swift

```
class TriangleAndSquare {
    var triangle: EquilateralTriangle {
        willSet {
            square.sideLength = newValue.sideLength
        }
    }
    var square: Square {
        willSet {
            triangle.sideLength = newValue.sideLength
        }
    }
    init(size: Double, name: String) {
        square = Square(sideLength: size, name: name)
        triangle = EquilateralTriangle(sideLength: size, name: name)
    }
}
var triangleAndSquare = TriangleAndSquare(size: 10, name: "another test shape")
print(triangleAndSquare.square.sideLength)
print(triangleAndSquare.triangle.sideLength)
triangleAndSquare.square = Square(sideLength: 50, name: "larger square")
print(triangleAndSquare.triangle.sideLength)
```

Protocols in swift are like interfaces in Java?
    Can anyone explain me what exactly do willSet and didSet in example above?

Comment: These are [property observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262), triggered when the property is set, not protocols. [Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) in Swift are another thing altogether. In answer to the question, protocols are analogous to Java interfaces, but property observers are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24071525/1271826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Property Observers

- Code in `willSet` gets called when the value of a property is about to change.
- On the other hand `didSet` gets called when the value of a property has just been changed.

### 2. Protocols

You can think of protocols as being like interfaces if it helps you, but you might want to [watch the WWDC video "Protocol-oriented programming"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/) to see how protocols are being used in practice.