# Java interface equivalent in Swift

Tags: java, ios, swift, interface, swift3

> **EDIT:** What is different between [**What is the equivalent for java interfaces or objective c protocols in swift?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071525/what-is-the-equivalent-for-java-interfaces-or-objective-c-protocols-in-swift) and this question?

After I read that topic, I thought It was an option to use a class to extend the protocol, and I tried to create the protocol itself with no success, but as Duncan C. said **it is not possible to initialise a protocol type directly** and I have to extend it with another class.

**My Problem:** I have a class in Java, I hold an array of interfaces, that way I can loop through the array and call the doWork() function until one of them returns true. I want to achieve the same functionality in Swift.

My java class:

```
class MyClass{
    //create a variable that holds all of my engines
    private MyEngine[] myEngines = new MyEngine[]{
        new MyEngine(){
            @Override
            public boolean doWork(){
                return doWork1();
            }        
        },
        new MyEngine(){
            @Override
            public boolean doWork(){
                return doWork2();
            }        
        },
        new MyEngine(){
            @Override
            public boolean doWork(){
                return doWork3();
            }        
        }
    }

    //loop through all engines until one of them succeed
    public boolean doWorkUntilSuccess(){
        for(int i = 0; i < myEngines.length; i++){
            if(myEngines[i].doWork())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean doWork1(){
        //code
        return result;
    }

    private boolean doWork2(){
        //code
        return result;
    }

    private boolean doWork3(){
        //code
        return result;
    }

    interface MyEngine{
        boolean doWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are asking somebody to translate your Java code into Swift without showing what you have done so far, you are likely to get negative votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Swift equivalent to an interface is a Protocol, as Connor says in his answer.

Again, borrowing from Connor's answer:

```
protocol MyEngine {
    func doWork() -> Bool
}
```

You can't instantiate objects of type MyEngine directly. Instead you need to define one or more objects that conform to the protocol:

```
class Obj1: MyEngine {
    func doWork() -> Bool {
        print("in Obj1 doWork()")
        return true
    }
}

class Obj2: MyEngine {
    func doWork() -> Bool {
        print("in Obj2 doWork()")
        return true
    }
}
```

You can then define an array of objects that conform to the protocol:

```
var objArray = [MyEngine]()
```

Then populate the array:

```
objArray.append(Obj1())
objArray.append(Obj2())
objArray.append(Obj2())
objArray.append(Obj1())
```

You can then say

```
objArray.forEach{$0.doWork()}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

```
protocol MyEngine {
    func doWork() -> Bool
}
```

Classes can then implement the protocol. However, there is no equivalent (to my knowledge) of saying `new MyEngine()`. You need to declare a class or struct that implements the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can put needed functions into array like that:

```
var firstFunction = {
    print("1")
}

var secondFunction = {
    print("2")
}

let functions: [() -> ()] = [firstFunction, secondFunction]

for function in functions {
    function()
}
```

Log output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The

> Java interface equivalent in Swift

is a protocol: [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1): Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Your MyEngine interface would look like this:

```
protocol MyEngine {
  func doWork() -> Bool
}
```

Though for the use case shown, you would probably just use a closure. Like so:

```
class WorkToDo {
  typealias WorkerFunc = () -> ()

  let workStuff : [ WorkerFunc ] = [
    { ... do work 1 ... },
    { ... do work 2 ... },
    { ... do work 3 ... }
  ]

  func doAllWork() {
    for work in workStuff {
      work()
    }
  }
}
```